# Can I have any way to detect the Driver Signing Policy status?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a modified driver and must be installed when driver signing is disabled, so I want to detect this status to remind users to reboot to SafeMode.
I had tried this command : `Bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING OFF`, but failed and prompted

> An error has occurred setting the element data.
>   The value is protected by Secure Boot policy and cannot be modified or deleted.

Umm..is there any way can do it?

————————

PS:
In fact, my laptop model is **MSI GS70 2PE**. I don't think it's a cheap one even the lastest published GS73 cannot supported full win10 gestures.And it supports Windows10 but MSI truly doesn't release the lastest driver.If I only modified and use it by myself, nothing worth mentioning.However, I want to share it in forum to help other general users to use.

Am I doing something wrong? Cannot understanding why someone talks about other things.

Comment: Why not give instructions to the user on what steps they need to take? Trying to automate this is likely to end in pain, as your users find their machines no longer function as before.

Comment: Remember, Microsoft is actively protecting users against people like you. Don't expect a permanent win. Don't be surprised by a permanent ban, e.g. being added to [Malicious Software Removal Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/malicious-software-removal-tool-details.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I guess there'll be some people don't follow all steps and consided of robustness maybe check the status automatically will be a better choice?After all, the incorrect installation of driver can be a serous error.@DavidHeffernan

Comment: Umm, from the risk side your warning worth thinking, however, in fact, my OEM laptop manufacturer doesn't release the lastest touchpad driver supported win10 and I have to modify it by myself.This is my trouble and thanks for your reply.@MSalters

Comment: Well, I epext getting your driver signed by someone (friend etc.) is not an option for you?

Comment: Signing the driver is the way forward. Trying to automate getting an unsigned driver onto a machine is just asking for trouble. If you don't want your users to have the inconvenience, why don't you get the driver signed?

Comment: *"my OEM laptop manufacturer doesn't release the lastest touchpad driver supported win10 and I have to modify it by myself."* - This means, that the OEM sold the laptop as a device running some version prior to Windows 10, and never promised to run Windows 10. The solution is to ask the OEM for Windows 10 support. The solution is not to fumble with **their** driver installers (legal issues aside). Lessons learned: If you buy cheap, cheap is what you get.

Comment: Thanks, if I can, I will try to do it.@DavidHeffernan

Answer (score 2):

I would rather wrap this into a nicer function like so:

```
bool IsSystemCodeIntegrityEnabled() {
        typedef NTSTATUS(__stdcall* td_NtQuerySystemInformation)(
                ULONG           SystemInformationClass,
                PVOID           SystemInformation,
                ULONG           SystemInformationLength,
                PULONG          ReturnLength
                );

        struct SYSTEM_CODEINTEGRITY_INFORMATION {
                ULONG Length;
                ULONG CodeIntegrityOptions;
        };

        static td_NtQuerySystemInformation NtQuerySystemInformation = (td_NtQuerySystemInformation)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"), "NtQuerySystemInformation");

        SYSTEM_CODEINTEGRITY_INFORMATION Integrity ={ sizeof(SYSTEM_CODEINTEGRITY_INFORMATION), 0 };
        NTSTATUS status = NtQuerySystemInformation(103, &Integrity, sizeof(Integrity), NULL);

        return (NT_SUCCESS(status) && (Integrity.CodeIntegrityOptions & 1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to detect whether or not `TESTSIGNING` is enabled:

```
#include <Winternl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll.lib")


//Check if testsigning is enabled
SYSTEM_CODEINTEGRITY_INFORMATION sci = {0};
ULONG dwcbSz = 0;
sci.Length = sizeof(sci);
if(NtQuerySystemInformation(
    /*SystemCodeIntegrityInformation*/ (SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS)0x67, 
    &sci, 
    sizeof(sci), 
    &dwcbSz) >= 0 &&
    dwcbSz == sizeof(sci))
{
    BOOL bTestsigningEnabled = !!(sci.CodeIntegrityOptions & /*CODEINTEGRITY_OPTION_TESTSIGN*/ 0x2);
    //Note that testsigning will play no role if bit CODEINTEGRITY_OPTION_ENABLED (or 0x1) is not set in sci.CodeIntegrityOptions

}
```

Comment: "Note that testsigning will play no role if bit CODEINTEGRITY_OPTION_ENABLED (or 0x1) is not set in sci.CodeIntegrityOptions" - This is incorrect. On Win 7 for example CODEINTEGRITY_OPTION_ENABLED is NOT set when Test Signing mode is ON.