# Driver Blue Screen of Death System Service Exception

Tags: c

I'm Trying to test this Sagaan AntiCheat but i got bluescreen i use OSRLoader to load the driver and its load perfectly but when i open the .exe it's give me Blue Screen of Death https://prnt.sc/m9zl6o
the Source code of the FullProject https://github.com/SagaanTheEpic/Sagaan-AntiCheat-V2.0 I cant see where is the error can someone help me analyze this project that im trying to build. i want to recode it to add more features and make it better more.

```css
#include <ntdef.h>
#include <ntifs.h>
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <ntdddisk.h>
#include <scsi.h>
#include <ntddscsi.h>
#include <mountdev.h>
#include <mountmgr.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ntifs.h>
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <windef.h>
#include <wdf.h>
#include <ntdef.h>

#include "BlackBone\VadRoutines.h"
#include "BlackBone\Routines.h"
#include "DriverIO.h"
#include "Formula.h"

DRIVER_INITIALIZE DriverEntry;
#pragma alloc_text(INIT, DriverEntry)
#define PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION      0x1000
#define SYSTEM_PROCESS_ID (HANDLE)4

PVOID ObHandle = NULL;

ULONG ProtectedProcess = 0;
ULONG UsermodeAntiCheat = 0;
ULONG ProtectionThreads[7];


VOID CreateThreadNotifyRoutine(
 IN HANDLE ProcessId,
 IN HANDLE ThreadId,
 IN BOOLEAN Create
);

// Terminating a process of your choice using the PID, usefull if the cheat is also using a driver to strip it's handles and therefore you can forcefully close it using the driver
NTSTATUS TerminateProcess(ULONG targetPid)
{
 if (targetPid == ProtectedProcess)
 {
  ProtectedProcess = 0;
 }
 if (targetPid == UsermodeAntiCheat)
 {
  UsermodeAntiCheat = 0;
 }

 NTSTATUS NtRet = ((NTSTATUS)0x00000000L);
 PEPROCESS PeProc = { 0 };
 NtRet = PsLookupProcessByProcessId(targetPid, &PeProc);
 if (NtRet != ((NTSTATUS)0x00000000L))
 {
  return NtRet;
 }
 HANDLE ProcessHandle;
 NtRet = ObOpenObjectByPointer(PeProc, NULL, NULL, 25, *PsProcessType, KernelMode, &ProcessHandle);
 if (NtRet != ((NTSTATUS)0x00000000L))
 {
  return NtRet;
 }
 ZwTerminateProcess(ProcessHandle, 0);
 ZwClose(ProcessHandle);
 return NtRet;
}

NTSTATUS DriverDispatchRoutine(PDEVICE_OBJECT pDeviceObject, PIRP pIrp)
{
 PVOID buffer;
 NTSTATUS NtStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;
 PIO_STACK_LOCATION pIo;
 pIo = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(pIrp);
 pIrp->IoStatus.Information = 0;
 switch (pIo->MajorFunction)
 {
 case IRP_MJ_CREATE:
  NtStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;
  break;
 case IRP_MJ_READ:
  NtStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;
  break;
 case IRP_MJ_WRITE:
  break;
 case IRP_MJ_CLOSE:
  NtStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;
  break;
 default:
  NtStatus = STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST;
  break;
 }
 pIrp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
 IoCompleteRequest(pIrp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
 return NtStatus;
}

// This will be called, if the driver is unloaded or just returns something
VOID DriverUnload(PDRIVER_OBJECT pDriverObject)
{
 DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "UNLOADED \n");
 UNICODE_STRING SACSymbolName;
 RtlInitUnicodeString(&SACSymbolName, L"\\DosDevices\\SACDriver"); // Giving the driver a symbol
 if (ObHandle)
 {
  ObUnRegisterCallbacks(ObHandle);
  ObHandle = NULL;
 }
 PsRemoveCreateThreadNotifyRoutine(CreateThreadNotifyRoutine);
 IoDeleteSymbolicLink(&SACSymbolName);
 IoDeleteDevice(pDriverObject->DeviceObject);
}


NTSTATUS Create(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP Irp)
{
 Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
 Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;

 IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
 return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
NTSTATUS Close(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP Irp)
{
 Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
 Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;

 IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
 return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

extern   NTSTATUS PsLookupProcessByProcessId(
 HANDLE ProcessId,
 PEPROCESS *Process
);




typedef struct _OB_REG_CONTEXT {
 USHORT Version;
 UNICODE_STRING Altitude;
 USHORT ulIndex;
 OB_OPERATION_REGISTRATION *OperationRegistration;
} REG_CONTEXT, *PREG_CONTEXT;

OB_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS ThreadPreCallback(PVOID RegistrationContext, POB_PRE_OPERATION_INFORMATION OperationInformation)
{
 UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistrationContext);

 if (OperationInformation->KernelHandle)
  return OB_PREOP_SUCCESS;

 if ((ULONG)PsGetCurrentProcessId() == UsermodeAntiCheat)
 {
  return OB_PREOP_SUCCESS;
 }
 if ((ULONG)PsGetCurrentProcessId() == ProtectedProcess)
 {
  return OB_PREOP_SUCCESS;
 }

 if (PsGetThreadProcessId(OperationInformation->Object) == UsermodeAntiCheat)
 {

  if (OperationInformation->Operation == OB_OPERATION_HANDLE_CREATE)
   OperationInformation->Parameters->CreateHandleInformation.DesiredAccess = (SYNCHRONIZE | THREAD_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION);
  else
   OperationInformation->Parameters->DuplicateHandleInformation.DesiredAccess = (SYNCHRONIZE | THREAD_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION);


 }
 else if (PsGetThreadProcessId(OperationInformation->Object) == ProtectedProcess)
 {

  if (OperationInformation->Operation == OB_OPERATION_HANDLE_CREATE)
   OperationInformation->Parameters->CreateHandleInformation.DesiredAccess = (SYNCHRONIZE | THREAD_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION);
  else
   OperationInformation->Parameters->DuplicateHandleInformation.DesiredAccess = (SYNCHRONIZE | THREAD_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION);


 }

 return OB_PREOP_SUCCESS;
}

OB_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS ProcessPreCallback(PVOID RegistrationContext, POB_PRE_OPERATION_INFORMATION OperationInformation)
{
 UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistrationContext);
 if (UsermodeAntiCheat == 0)
  return OB_PREOP_SUCCESS;

 if (ProtectedProcess == 0)
  return OB_PREOP_SUCCESS;

 PEPROCESS ProtectedProcessPEPROCESS;
 PEPROCESS ProtectedUserModeACPEPROCESS;

 PEPROCESS OpenedProcess = (PEPROCESS)OperationInformation->Object,
  CurrentProcess = PsGetCurrentProcess();

 ULONG ulProcessId = PsGetProcessId(OpenedProcess);

 PsLookupProcessByProcessId(ProtectedProcess, &ProtectedProcessPEPROCESS);
 PsLookupProcessByProcessId(ProtectedProcess, &ProtectedUserModeACPEPROCESS);

 if (OperationInformation->KernelHandle)
  return OB_PREOP_SUCCESS;

 if (ProtectedProcess != 0)
 {
  if (PsGetProcessId((PEPROCESS)OperationInformation->Object) == ProtectedProcess)
  {

   if (OperationInformation->Operation == OB_OPERATION_HANDLE_CREATE) // striping handle 
   {
    OperationInformation->Parameters->CreateHandleInformation.DesiredAccess = (SYNCHRONIZE);
   }
   else
   {
    OperationInformation->Parameters->DuplicateHandleInformation.DesiredAccess = (SYNCHRONIZE);
   }
   return OB_PREOP_SUCCESS;
  }
 }

 if (UsermodeAntiCheat != 0)
 {
  if (PsGetProcessId((PEPROCESS)OperationInformation->Object) == UsermodeAntiCheat)
  {

   if (OperationInformation->Operation == OB_OPERATION_HANDLE_CREATE) // striping handle 
   {
    OperationInformation->Parameters->CreateHandleInformation.DesiredAccess = (SYNCHRONIZE);
   }
   else
   {
    OperationInformation->Parameters->DuplicateHandleInformation.DesiredAccess = (SYNCHRONIZE);
   }
   return OB_PREOP_SUCCESS;
  }
 }
 return OB_PREOP_SUCCESS;
}

VOID CreateThreadNotifyRoutine(
 IN HANDLE ProcessId,
 IN HANDLE ThreadId,
 IN BOOLEAN Create
)
{
 if (!Create)
 {
  if (UsermodeAntiCheat == ProcessId)
  {
   for (int x = 0; x > 8; x++)
   {
    if ((ULONG)ThreadId == ProtectionThreads[x])
    {

     TerminateProcess(ProtectedProcess);
     TerminateProcess(UsermodeAntiCheat);
    }
   }

  }

  if (ProtectedProcess == ProcessId)
  {

  }

 }
}


VOID EnableCallBack()
{
 NTSTATUS NtHandleCallback = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
 NTSTATUS NtThreadCallback = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;

 OB_OPERATION_REGISTRATION OBOperationRegistration[2];
 OB_CALLBACK_REGISTRATION OBOCallbackRegistration;
 REG_CONTEXT regContext;
 UNICODE_STRING usAltitude;
 memset(&OBOperationRegistration, 0, sizeof(OB_OPERATION_REGISTRATION));
 memset(&OBOCallbackRegistration, 0, sizeof(OB_CALLBACK_REGISTRATION));
 memset(&regContext, 0, sizeof(REG_CONTEXT));
 regContext.ulIndex = 1;
 regContext.Version = 120;
 RtlInitUnicodeString(&usAltitude, L"1000");

 if ((USHORT)ObGetFilterVersion() == OB_FLT_REGISTRATION_VERSION)
 {
  //OBOperationRegistration.ObjectType = PsProcessType; // Use To Strip Handle Permissions For Threads PsThreadType
  //OBOperationRegistration.Operations = OB_OPERATION_HANDLE_CREATE | OB_OPERATION_HANDLE_DUPLICATE;
  //OBOperationRegistration.PostOperation = PostCallBack; // Giving the function which happens after creating
  //OBOperationRegistration.PreOperation = PreCallback; // Giving the function which happens before creating

  OBOperationRegistration[1].ObjectType = PsProcessType;
  OBOperationRegistration[1].Operations = OB_OPERATION_HANDLE_CREATE | OB_OPERATION_HANDLE_DUPLICATE;
  OBOperationRegistration[1].PreOperation = ProcessPreCallback;
  OBOperationRegistration[1].PostOperation = NULL;


  OBOperationRegistration[0].ObjectType = PsThreadType;
  OBOperationRegistration[0].Operations = OB_OPERATION_HANDLE_CREATE | OB_OPERATION_HANDLE_DUPLICATE;
  OBOperationRegistration[0].PreOperation = ThreadPreCallback;
  OBOperationRegistration[0].PostOperation = NULL;

  OBOCallbackRegistration.Version = OB_FLT_REGISTRATION_VERSION;
  OBOCallbackRegistration.OperationRegistrationCount = 2;
  OBOCallbackRegistration.RegistrationContext = NULL;
  OBOCallbackRegistration.OperationRegistration = &OBOperationRegistration;

  NtHandleCallback = ObRegisterCallbacks(&OBOCallbackRegistration, &ObHandle); // Register The CallBack
  PsSetCreateThreadNotifyRoutine(CreateThreadNotifyRoutine);

  if (!NT_SUCCESS(NtHandleCallback))
  {
   if (ObHandle)
   {
    ObUnRegisterCallbacks(ObHandle);
    ObHandle = NULL;
   }
   DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Error: ObRegisterCallbacks Has Failed\n");
  }
  else
  {

  }
 }
}

static ULONG KsecRandomSeed = 0x62b409a1;

NTSTATUS
NTAPI
KsecGenRandom(
 PVOID Buffer,
 SIZE_T Length)
{
 LARGE_INTEGER TickCount;
 ULONG i, RandomValue;
 PULONG P;

 /* Try to generate a more random seed */
 KeQueryTickCount(&TickCount);
 KsecRandomSeed ^= _rotl(TickCount.LowPart, (KsecRandomSeed % 23));

 P = Buffer;
 for (i = 0; i < Length / sizeof(ULONG); i++)
 {
  P[i] = RtlRandomEx(&KsecRandomSeed);
 }

 Length &= (sizeof(ULONG) - 1);
 if (Length > 0)
 {
  RandomValue = RtlRandomEx(&KsecRandomSeed);
  RtlCopyMemory(&P[i], &RandomValue, Length);
 }

 return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

ULONG FOR1 = 100, FOR2 = 200, FOR3 = 300, FOR4 = 400, FOR5 = 500;
ULONG Encryption_Forward1 = 1, Encryption_Forward2 = 1, Encryption_Forward3 = 1, Encryption_Forward4 = 1, Encryption_Forward5 = 1;

BOOL Request_1 = FALSE;

BOOLEAN ProtectedGameRecieved = FALSE;
BOOLEAN UsermodeAntiCheatRecieved = FALSE;
NTSTATUS IoControl(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP Irp)
{


 NTSTATUS Status;
 ULONG BytesIO = 0;

 PIO_STACK_LOCATION stack = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);

 // Code received from user space
 ULONG ControlCode = stack->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.IoControlCode;

 if (ControlCode == IO_SEND_CURRENTPROCESS && UsermodeAntiCheat < 1)
 {
  PKERNEL_READ_REQUEST ReadInput = (PKERNEL_READ_REQUEST)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
  UsermodeAntiCheat = ReadInput->UsermodeProgram;

  Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
  BytesIO = sizeof(KERNEL_READ_REQUEST);
 }


 if ((ULONG)UsermodeAntiCheat == (ULONG)PsGetProcessId(PsGetCurrentProcess()))
 {

  if (ControlCode == IO_SEND_PROCESSID && ProtectedGameRecieved == FALSE)
  {

   PKERNEL_READ_REQUEST ReadInput = (PKERNEL_READ_REQUEST)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
   ProtectedProcess = ReadInput->GameProcess;

   if (ProtectedProcess > 0)
   {
    ProtectedGameRecieved = TRUE;
   }

   Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
   BytesIO = sizeof(KERNEL_READ_REQUEST);

  }

  else if (ControlCode == IO_PROTECTIONT_THREADS)
  {
   PKERNEL_THREAD_REQUEST ReadInput = (PKERNEL_THREAD_REQUEST)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
   ProtectionThreads[0] = ReadInput->ThreadID;
   ProtectionThreads[1] = ReadInput->ThreadID2;
   ProtectionThreads[2] = ReadInput->ThreadID3;
   ProtectionThreads[3] = ReadInput->ThreadID4;
   ProtectionThreads[4] = ReadInput->ThreadID5;
   ProtectionThreads[5] = ReadInput->ThreadID6;
   ProtectionThreads[6] = ReadInput->ThreadID7;
   ProtectionThreads[7] = ReadInput->ThreadID8;

   Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
   BytesIO = sizeof(KERNEL_THREAD_REQUEST);
  }
  else if (ControlCode == IO_TerminateProcess)
  {
   PKERNEL_READ_REQUEST ReadInput = (PKERNEL_READ_REQUEST)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;

   TerminateProcess(ReadInput->UsermodeProgram);

   Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
   BytesIO = sizeof(KERNEL_READ_REQUEST);

  }
  else if (ControlCode == HEARTBEATMAINSTART_FORWARD)
  {


   PKERNEL_HEARTBEAT_REQUEST ReadInput = (PKERNEL_HEARTBEAT_REQUEST)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;


   Encryption_Forward1 = ReadInput->Encrypt1;
   Encryption_Forward2 = ReadInput->Encrypt2;
   Encryption_Forward3 = ReadInput->Encrypt3;
   Encryption_Forward4 = ReadInput->Encrypt4;
   Encryption_Forward5 = ReadInput->Encrypt5;



   Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
   BytesIO = sizeof(KERNEL_HEARTBEAT_REQUEST);


  }
  else if (ControlCode == HEARTBEATMAINSTART_RETURN)
  {


   PKERNEL_HEARTBEAT_REQUEST ReadInput = (PKERNEL_HEARTBEAT_REQUEST)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;


   ReadInput->Encrypt1 = Formula1(Encryption_Forward1);
   ReadInput->Encrypt2 = Formula2(Encryption_Forward2);
   ReadInput->Encrypt3 = Formula3(Encryption_Forward3);
   ReadInput->Encrypt4 = Formula4(Encryption_Forward4);
   ReadInput->Encrypt5 = Formula5(Encryption_Forward5);

   //DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "HEARTBEATMAINSTART_RETURN Called: Formula1(Encryption_Forward1) %d", Formula1(Encryption_Forward1));

   Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
   BytesIO = sizeof(KERNEL_HEARTBEAT_REQUEST);


  }
  else if (ControlCode == HEARTBEATCREATEPROCESS_RETURN)
  {
   PKERNEL_HEARTBEAT_REQUEST ReadInput = (PKERNEL_HEARTBEAT_REQUEST)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
   KsecGenRandom(FOR1, sizeof(FOR1));
   KsecGenRandom(FOR2, sizeof(FOR2));
   KsecGenRandom(FOR3, sizeof(FOR3));
   KsecGenRandom(FOR4, sizeof(FOR4));
   KsecGenRandom(FOR5, sizeof(FOR5));


   ReadInput->Encrypt1 = FOR1;
   ReadInput->Encrypt2 = FOR2;
   ReadInput->Encrypt3 = FOR3;
   ReadInput->Encrypt4 = FOR4;
   ReadInput->Encrypt5 = FOR5;

   Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
   BytesIO = sizeof(KERNEL_HEARTBEAT_REQUEST);


  }
  else if (ControlCode == IO_VADPROTECTION)
  {
   PHIDE_VAD ReadInput = (PHIDE_VAD)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
   if (ReadInput->pid == ProtectedProcess || ReadInput == UsermodeAntiCheat)
   {
    // Enable it if you like. I dont need it so eh
    //BBHideVAD(ReadInput);
   }

   Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
   BytesIO = sizeof(HIDE_VAD);
  }
  else if (ControlCode == HEARTBEATCREATEPROCESS_FORWARD)
  {
   PKERNEL_HEARTBEAT_REQUEST ReadInput = (PKERNEL_HEARTBEAT_REQUEST)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;

   if (ReadInput->Encrypt1 == Formula1(FOR1))
   {
    if (ReadInput->Encrypt2 == Formula2(FOR2))
    {
     if (ReadInput->Encrypt3 == Formula3(FOR3))
     {
      if (ReadInput->Encrypt4 == Formula4(FOR4))
      {
       if (ReadInput->Encrypt5 == Formula5(FOR5))
       {
        //DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Process Id ( IOCONTROL )%s\n", (ULONG)PsGetProcessId(IoGetCurrentProcess()));
        Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
        // GOOD
       }
       else
       {
        if (ProtectedProcess)
        {
         TerminateProcess(ProtectedProcess);
        }
        TerminateProcess(UsermodeAntiCheat);
        Status = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
        //BAD
        // ERROR
        // TERMINATE GAME OR PROTECTION 
        // BLUE SCREEN OF DEATH OR WHATEVER YOU LIKE
        DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Error: ReadInput->Encrypt5 == Formula5(FOR5) Encrypt: %s Formula: %s \n", ReadInput->Encrypt5, Formula5(FOR5));
       }
      }
      else
      {
       if (ProtectedProcess)
       {

        TerminateProcess(ProtectedProcess);
       }
       TerminateProcess(UsermodeAntiCheat);
       Status = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;


       //BAD
       // ERROR
       // TERMINATE GAME OR PROTECTION 
       // BLUE SCREEN OF DEATH OR WHATEVER YOU LIKE
       DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Error: ReadInput->Encrypt4 == Formula4(FOR4) Encrypt: %s Formula: %s \n", ReadInput->Encrypt4, Formula4(FOR4));
      }
     }
     else
     {
      if (ProtectedProcess)
      {
       TerminateProcess(ProtectedProcess);
      }
      TerminateProcess(UsermodeAntiCheat);
      Status = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
      //BAD
      // ERROR
      // TERMINATE GAME OR PROTECTION 
      // BLUE SCREEN OF DEATH OR WHATEVER YOU LIKE
      DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Error: ReadInput->Encrypt3 == Formula3(FOR3) Encrypt: %s Formula: %s \n", ReadInput->Encrypt3, Formula3(FOR3));
     }
    }
    else
    {
     if (ProtectedProcess)
     {
      TerminateProcess(ProtectedProcess);
     }
     TerminateProcess(UsermodeAntiCheat);
     Status = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
     //BAD
     // ERROR
     // TERMINATE GAME OR PROTECTION 
     // BLUE SCREEN OF DEATH OR WHATEVER YOU LIKE
     DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Error: ReadInput->Encrypt2 == Formula2(FOR2) Encrypt: %s Formula: %s \n", ReadInput->Encrypt2, Formula2(FOR2));
    }
   }
   else
   {
    if (ProtectedProcess)
    {
     TerminateProcess(ProtectedProcess);
    }
    TerminateProcess(UsermodeAntiCheat);
    Status = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    //BAD
    // ERROR
    // TERMINATE GAME OR PROTECTION 
    // BLUE SCREEN OF DEATH OR WHATEVER YOU LIKE
    DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "Error: ReadInput->Encrypt1 == Formula1(FOR1) Encrypt: %s Formula: %s \n", ReadInput->Encrypt1, Formula1(FOR1));
   }

   BytesIO = sizeof(KERNEL_HEARTBEAT_REQUEST);

  }

 }
 else if ((ULONG)ProtectedProcess == (ULONG)PsGetProcessId(PsGetCurrentProcess()))
 {
  if (ControlCode == IO_RETURNANTICHEATUSERMODE_PROCESSID_GMAE)
  {
   PKERNEL_READ_REQUEST ReadInput = (PKERNEL_READ_REQUEST)Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
   ReadInput->UsermodeProgram = UsermodeAntiCheat;


   Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
   BytesIO = sizeof(KERNEL_READ_REQUEST);

  }
 }

 // Complete the request
 Irp->IoStatus.Status = Status;
 Irp->IoStatus.Information = BytesIO;
 IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);

 return Status;
}

// Driver's Main function. This will be called and looped through till returned, or unloaded.
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT pDriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING pUniStr)
{
 DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "LOADED \n");
 UNICODE_STRING SACDriverName, SACSymbolName;
 NTSTATUS NtRet = STATUS_SUCCESS;
 PDEVICE_OBJECT pDeviceObj;
 RtlInitUnicodeString(&SACDriverName, L"\\Device\\SACDriver"); // Giving the driver a name
 RtlInitUnicodeString(&SACSymbolName, L"\\DosDevices\\SACDriver"); // Giving the driver a symbol
 UNICODE_STRING deviceNameUnicodeString, deviceSymLinkUnicodeString;
 NTSTATUS NtRet2 = IoCreateDevice(pDriverObject, 0, &SACDriverName, FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, FILE_DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN, FALSE, &pDeviceObj);

 IoCreateSymbolicLink(&SACSymbolName, &SACDriverName);

 pDriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CREATE] = Create;
 pDriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CLOSE] = Close;
 pDriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL] = IoControl;

 pDeviceObj->Flags |= DO_DIRECT_IO;
 pDeviceObj->Flags &= (~DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING);

 pDriverObject->DriverUnload = DriverUnload;

 EnableCallBack();

 return NtRet;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why i got bluescreen of death because of this rand() function.

```css
#include "DLLInjectorDector.h"
#include "AbortFailureDetects.h"
#include "DriverLoader\\driver.h"
#include "DriverIO.h"
#include "openssl\\md5.h"
#include "DriverIORequests.h"
#include "Formulas.h"
#include "Anti Debug.h"
#include "DLLInjectionDetector\Utils.h"
#include "Utlis.h"
#include "NamePipe.h"
#include "DigitalSignatureChecker.h"

#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Softpub.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <wintrust.h>
#include <sys/types.h>  
#include <signal.h> 
#include <vector>

// Link with the Wintrust.lib file.
#pragma comment (lib, "wintrust")


// Varibles
HANDLE hDriver; // Driver
ULONG NamePipe1, NamePipe2, NamePipe3, NamePipe4, NamePipe5;
ULONG FOR1, FOR2, FOR3, FOR4, FOR5;
ULONG CHECK1, CHECK2, CHECK3, CHECK4, CHECK5;
ULONG CHECK_CREATEPROCESS1, CHECK_CREATEPROCESS2, CHECK_CREATEPROCESS3, CHECK_CREATEPROCESS4, CHECK_CREATEPROCESS5;
int GameProcessID = 0;

// Functions
bool CheckTestMode();
int randNum(int min, int max);

DWORD TidHeartBeat = 0;
DWORD TidGameValidChech = 0;
DWORD TidAntiDebug = 0;
DWORD tidDriverScanner = 0;
DWORD TidCommonCheatScanner = 0;
DWORD TidOverlayScanner = 0;
DWORD TidAntiKill = 0;
DWORD TidMainThread = 0;

BOOL HeartBeatThreadAntiKill = FALSE;
HANDLE hHeartBeatThread = NULL;
DWORD WINAPI HeartBeatThread()
{
 AntiDebug::HideThread(GetCurrentThread());
 while (1)
 {
  srand(time(0));
  FOR1 = randNum(2, 63);
  FOR2 = randNum(3, 34);
  FOR3 = randNum(8, 45);
  FOR4 = randNum(5, 67);
  FOR5 = randNum(2, 12);

  if (DriverRequest::HEARTBEATMAINSTART_FORWARD_Function(FOR1, FOR2, FOR3, FOR4, FOR5))
  {
   KERNEL_HEARTBEAT_REQUEST RETURNED_HEARTBEAT_CREATEPROCESS = DriverRequest::HEARTBEATMAINSTART_RETURN_Function();


   if (RETURNED_HEARTBEAT_CREATEPROCESS.Encrypt1 == HeartbeatFormula::Formula1(FOR1))
   {
    if (RETURNED_HEARTBEAT_CREATEPROCESS.Encrypt2 == HeartbeatFormula::Formula2(FOR2))
    {
     if (RETURNED_HEARTBEAT_CREATEPROCESS.Encrypt3 == HeartbeatFormula::Formula3(FOR3))
     {
      if (RETURNED_HEARTBEAT_CREATEPROCESS.Encrypt4 == HeartbeatFormula::Formula4(FOR4))
      {
       if (RETURNED_HEARTBEAT_CREATEPROCESS.Encrypt5 == HeartbeatFormula::Formula5(FOR5))
       {
        KERNEL_HEARTBEAT_REQUEST RETURNED_HEARTBEAT_CREATEPROCESS_CREATEPROCESS = DriverRequest::HEARTBEATCREATEPROCESS_RETURN_Function();

        CHECK_CREATEPROCESS1 = HeartbeatFormula::Formula1(RETURNED_HEARTBEAT_CREATEPROCESS_CREATEPROCESS.Encrypt1);
        CHECK_CREATEPROCESS2 = HeartbeatFormula::Formula2(RETURNED_HEARTBEAT_CREATEPROCESS_CREATEPROCESS.Encrypt2);
        CHECK_CREATEPROCESS3 = HeartbeatFormula::Formula3(RETURNED_HEARTBEAT_CREATEPROCESS_CREATEPROCESS.Encrypt3);
        CHECK_CREATEPROCESS4 = HeartbeatFormula::Formula4(RETURNED_HEARTBEAT_CREATEPROCESS_CREATEPROCESS.Encrypt4);
        CHECK_CREATEPROCESS5 = HeartbeatFormula::Formula5(RETURNED_HEARTBEAT_CREATEPROCESS_CREATEPROCESS.Encrypt5);
        if (DriverRequest::HEARTBEATCREATEPROCESS_FORWARD_Function(CHECK_CREATEPROCESS1, CHECK_CREATEPROCESS2, CHECK_CREATEPROCESS3, CHECK_CREATEPROCESS4, CHECK_CREATEPROCESS5))
        {
         if ( CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(TidMainThread))
         {
          ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("63452 ( Thread Mismatched )", 6);
         }

         HeartBeatThreadAntiKill = TRUE;
         Sleep(400);
        }
        else
        {
         ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("601 ( HeartBeat System Failed )", 5);
         Sleep(3000);
         exit(1);
        }

       }
       else
       {
        ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("602 ( HeartBeat System Failed )", 5);
        Sleep(3000);
        exit(1);
       }
      }
      else
      {
       ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("603 ( HeartBeat System Failed )", 5);
       Sleep(3000);
       exit(1);
      }
     }
     else
     {
      ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("604 ( HeartBeat System Failed )", 5);
      Sleep(3000);
      exit(1);
     }
    }
    else
    {
     ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("605 ( HeartBeat System Failed )", 5);
     Sleep(3000);
     exit(1);
    }
   }
   else
   {
    ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("606 ( HeartBeat System Failed )", 5);
    Sleep(3000);
    exit(1);
   }
  }
  else
  {
   ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("607 ( HeartBeat System Failed )", 5);
   Sleep(3000);
   exit(1);
  }
 }
 return 0;
}


BOOL GameCheckerAntiKill = FALSE;
HANDLE hGameChecker = NULL;
DWORD WINAPI GameValidCheckThread()
{
 AntiDebug::HideThread(GetCurrentThread());
 while (1)
 {
  if (GameProcessID == 0)
  {
   Sleep(200);
  }
  else
  {
   if (!ErrorHandler::isProcessRunning(GameProcessID))
   {
    ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("901 ( Game Stopped Running )", 3);
   }
  }

  if (CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(TidAntiDebug)
   || CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(TidAntiKill))
  {
   ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("32156 ( Thread Mismatched )", 6);
  }

  GameCheckerAntiKill = TRUE;
 }
}


BOOL AntiDebugAntiKill = FALSE;
HANDLE hAntiDebug = NULL;
DWORD WINAPI AntiDebugThread()
{
 AntiDebug::HideThread(GetCurrentThread());
 while (1)
 {
  if (AntiDebug::CheckRemoteDebuggerPresentAPI())
  {
   ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("701", 6);
  }
  Sleep(200);
  if (AntiDebug::IsDebuggerPresentAPI())
  {
   ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("702", 6);
  }
  Sleep(200);
  if (AntiDebug::HardwareBreakpoints())
  {
   ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("703", 6);
  }
  Sleep(200);
  if (AntiDebug::MemoryBreakpoints_PageGuard())
  {
   ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("704", 6);
  }
  Sleep(200);
  if (AntiDebug::UnhandledExcepFilterTest())
  {
   ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("706", 6);
  }
  Sleep(200);
  if (AntiDebug::SharedUserData_KernelDebugger())
  {
   ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("707", 6);
  }
  Sleep(200);

  if (CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(TidAntiDebug)
   || CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(TidAntiKill))
  {
   ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("34524 ( Thread Mismatched )", 6);
  }

  AntiDebugAntiKill = TRUE;
 }
}


BOOL DriversScanAntiKill = FALSE;
HANDLE hDriversScan = NULL;
DWORD WINAPI DriversScanThread()
{
 AntiDebug::HideThread(GetCurrentThread());
 while (1)
 {
  LPVOID drivers[1024];
  DWORD cbNeeded;
  int cDrivers, i;

  if (EnumDeviceDrivers(drivers, sizeof(drivers), &cbNeeded) && cbNeeded < sizeof(drivers))
  {
   /*
   TCHAR szDriver[1024];

   cDrivers = cbNeeded / sizeof(drivers[0]);

   for (i = 0; i < cDrivers; i++)
   {
    if (GetDeviceDriverBaseName(drivers[i], szDriver, sizeof(szDriver) / sizeof(szDriver[0])))
    {
     TCHAR szName[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };

     GetDeviceDriverFileName(drivers[i], szName, MAX_PATH);
     //_tprintf(TEXT("%d: %s\n"), i + 1, szName);
     Sleep(10);
    }
   }*/
   Sleep(100);
  }
  else
  {
   ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("9753 ( Please Restart Your PC )", 5);
  }

  if (CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(TidAntiDebug)
   || CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(TidAntiKill))
  {
   ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("565435 ( Thread Mismatched )", 6);
  }
  DriversScanAntiKill = TRUE;
 }
}


BOOL CommonCheatsScannerAntiKill = FALSE;
HANDLE hCommonCheatsScanner = NULL;
DWORD WINAPI CommonCheatsScannerThread()
{
 AntiDebug::HideThread(GetCurrentThread());
 while (1)
 {
  const char DebuggingDrivers[9][20] = {
   "\\\\.\\EXTREM", "\\\\.\\ICEEXT",
   "\\\\.\\NDBGMSG.VXD", "\\\\.\\RING0",
   "\\\\.\\SIWVID", "\\\\.\\SYSER",
   "\\\\.\\TRW", "\\\\.\\SYSERBOOT",
   "\0"
  };


  for (int i = 0; DebuggingDrivers[i][0] != '\0'; i++) {
   HANDLE h = CreateFileA(DebuggingDrivers[i], 0, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
   if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
    CloseHandle(h);
    ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("2001 ( Debugging Drivers Found )", 6);
   }
   CloseHandle(h);
   Sleep(200);
  }

  const char CheatingDrivers[5][20] = {
   "\\\\.\\kernelhop", "\\\\.\\BlackBone",
   "\\\\.\\VBoxDrv", "\\\\.\\Htsysm72FB",
   "\0"
  };


  for (int i = 0; CheatingDrivers[i][0] != '\0'; i++) {
   HANDLE hCheats = CreateFileA(CheatingDrivers[i], 0, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
   if (hCheats != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
    CloseHandle(hCheats);
    ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("3001 ( Cheating Drivers Found )", 2);
   }
   CloseHandle(hCheats);
   Sleep(200);
  }

  if (CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(TidAntiDebug)
   || CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(TidAntiKill))
  {
   ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("34536 ( Thread Mismatched )", 6);
  }

  CommonCheatsScannerAntiKill = TRUE;
  Sleep(200);
 }
}


BOOL OverlayScannerAntiKill = FALSE;
HANDLE hOverlayScanner = NULL;
DWORD WINAPI OverlayScannerThread()
{
 // https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/anti-cheat-bypass/263403-window-hijacking-dont-overlay-betray.html
 AntiDebug::HideThread(GetCurrentThread());
 while (1)
 {
  OverlayFinderParams params;
  params.style = WS_VISIBLE;
  params.styleEx = WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
  params.percentMainScreen = 90.0f;
  params.satisfyAllCriteria = true;
  std::vector<HWND> hwnds = Utlis::OverlayFinder(params);

  for (int i(0); i < hwnds.size(); ++i) {
   DWORD ProcessIDForOverlay = 0;
   DWORD tid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnds[i], &ProcessIDForOverlay);
   if (ErrorHandler::isProcessRunning(ProcessIDForOverlay))
   {
    DriverRequest::TerminatePrcoess(ProcessIDForOverlay);
    Sleep(200);
   }
   Sleep(200);
  }

  OverlayScannerAntiKill = TRUE;
  Sleep(200);
 }

}


BOOL AntiKillBool = FALSE;
HANDLE hAntiKill = NULL;
DWORD WINAPI AntiKillThread()
{
 AntiDebug::HideThread(GetCurrentThread());
 while (1)
 {
  if (CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(TidHeartBeat)
   || CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(tidDriverScanner)
   || CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(TidCommonCheatScanner)
   || CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(TidOverlayScanner)
   || CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(TidGameValidChech)
   || CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(TidMainThread)
   || CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(TidAntiDebug))
  {
   ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("34536 ( Thread Mismatched )", 6);
  }
  else
  {
   Sleep(200);
  }
 }

}


bool IsSystemCodeIntegrityEnabled()
{
 //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084077/can-i-have-any-way-to-detect-the-driver-signing-policy-status/50944791
 typedef NTSTATUS(__stdcall* td_NtQuerySystemInformation)(
  ULONG           SystemInformationClass,
  PVOID           SystemInformation,
  ULONG           SystemInformationLength,
  PULONG          ReturnLength
  );

 struct SYSTEM_CODEINTEGRITY_INFORMATION {
  ULONG Length;
  ULONG CodeIntegrityOptions;
 };

 static td_NtQuerySystemInformation NtQuerySystemInformation = (td_NtQuerySystemInformation)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"), "NtQuerySystemInformation");

 SYSTEM_CODEINTEGRITY_INFORMATION Integrity = { sizeof(SYSTEM_CODEINTEGRITY_INFORMATION), 0 };
 NTSTATUS status = NtQuerySystemInformation(103, &Integrity, sizeof(Integrity), NULL);

 return (status && (Integrity.CodeIntegrityOptions & 1));
}

void OnExit()
{
 if (GameProcessID != 0)
 {
  if (ErrorHandler::isProcessRunning(GameProcessID))
  {
   DriverRequest::TerminatePrcoess(GameProcessID);
  }
 }
 ErrorHandler::UnloadDriver();

}


int main()
{
 using namespace std;
 //FreeConsole();
 InitializeDLLCheck();
 InitializeThreadCheck();
 TidMainThread = GetCurrentThreadId();

 if (IsSystemCodeIntegrityEnabled())
 {
  ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("0392 Test Mode Is Enabled. Please Disable It", 6);
 }

 if (Utlis::IsRunAsAdministrator)
 {
  HANDLE CheckHandle = CreateFileA("\\\\.\\SACDriver", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
   FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

  if (CheckHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
   ErrorHandler::UnloadDriver();
   CloseHandle(CheckHandle);
  }

  ErrorHandler::LoadDriver();
  Sleep(100);
  hDriver = CreateFileA("\\\\.\\SACDriver", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
   FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);


  //printf("File Size: %d \n", WhiteListedDLLs::GetFileSize("SAC-V2-DLL.dll"));

  if (hDriver)
  {
   if (DriverRequest::SendCurrentProcessID())
   {
    hAntiDebug = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)AntiDebugThread, NULL, 0, &TidAntiDebug);

    srand(time(0));
    FOR1 = randNum(1, 35);
    FOR2 = randNum(1, 23);
    FOR3 = randNum(1, 23);
    FOR4 = randNum(1, 23);
    FOR5 = randNum(1, 34);
    if (DriverRequest::HEARTBEATMAINSTART_FORWARD_Function(FOR1, FOR2, FOR3, FOR4, FOR5))
    {
     KERNEL_HEARTBEAT_REQUEST RETURNED_HEARTBEAT = DriverRequest::HEARTBEATMAINSTART_RETURN_Function();

     ULONG TEST1 = HeartbeatFormula::Formula1(FOR1);
     ULONG TEST2 = RETURNED_HEARTBEAT.Encrypt1;

     if (RETURNED_HEARTBEAT.Encrypt1 == HeartbeatFormula::Formula1(FOR1))
     {
      if (RETURNED_HEARTBEAT.Encrypt2 == HeartbeatFormula::Formula2(FOR2))
      {
       if (RETURNED_HEARTBEAT.Encrypt3 == HeartbeatFormula::Formula3(FOR3))
       {
        if (RETURNED_HEARTBEAT.Encrypt4 == HeartbeatFormula::Formula4(FOR4))
        {
         if (RETURNED_HEARTBEAT.Encrypt5 == HeartbeatFormula::Formula5(FOR5))
         {

          KERNEL_HEARTBEAT_REQUEST RETURNED_HEARTBEAT_CREATEPROCESS = DriverRequest::HEARTBEATCREATEPROCESS_RETURN_Function();

          CHECK_CREATEPROCESS1 = HeartbeatFormula::Formula1(RETURNED_HEARTBEAT_CREATEPROCESS.Encrypt1);
          CHECK_CREATEPROCESS2 = HeartbeatFormula::Formula2(RETURNED_HEARTBEAT_CREATEPROCESS.Encrypt2);
          CHECK_CREATEPROCESS3 = HeartbeatFormula::Formula3(RETURNED_HEARTBEAT_CREATEPROCESS.Encrypt3);
          CHECK_CREATEPROCESS4 = HeartbeatFormula::Formula4(RETURNED_HEARTBEAT_CREATEPROCESS.Encrypt4);
          CHECK_CREATEPROCESS5 = HeartbeatFormula::Formula5(RETURNED_HEARTBEAT_CREATEPROCESS.Encrypt5);

          if (DriverRequest::HEARTBEATCREATEPROCESS_FORWARD_Function(CHECK_CREATEPROCESS1, CHECK_CREATEPROCESS2, CHECK_CREATEPROCESS3, CHECK_CREATEPROCESS4, CHECK_CREATEPROCESS5))
          {
           hHeartBeatThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)HeartBeatThread, NULL, 0, &TidHeartBeat);
           hDriversScan = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)DriversScanThread, NULL, 0, &tidDriverScanner);
           hCommonCheatsScanner = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)CommonCheatsScannerThread, NULL, 0, &TidCommonCheatScanner);
           hOverlayScanner = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)OverlayScannerThread, NULL, 0, &TidOverlayScanner);


           STARTUPINFO StartupInfo = { sizeof(StartupInfo) };
           PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo;
           if (CreateProcess("D:\\SteamLibrary\\steamapps\\common\\Kingdom New Lands\\Kingdom.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &StartupInfo, &ProcessInfo))
           {
            BlockInput(TRUE);
            Utlis::Injection(L"SAC-V2-DLL.dll", ProcessInfo.dwProcessId);
            GameProcessID = ProcessInfo.dwProcessId;
            if (DriverRequest::SendProcessIDs(GameProcessID))
            {
             CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
             CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
             

             BlockInput(FALSE);

             hGameChecker = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GameValidCheckThread, NULL, 0, &TidGameValidChech);
             hAntiKill = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)AntiKillThread, NULL, 0, &TidAntiKill);

             KERNEL_THREAD_REQUEST Threads;

             Threads.ThreadID = TidAntiDebug;
             Threads.ThreadID2 = TidHeartBeat;
             Threads.ThreadID3 = tidDriverScanner;
             Threads.ThreadID4 = TidCommonCheatScanner;
             Threads.ThreadID5 = TidOverlayScanner;
             Threads.ThreadID6 = TidGameValidChech;
             Threads.ThreadID7 = TidAntiKill;
             Threads.ThreadID8 = TidMainThread;

             if (DriverRequest::SendProtectedThreadID(Threads))
             {
              while (1)
              {
               atexit(OnExit);
               Sleep(4000);
               if (CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(TidHeartBeat)
                || CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(tidDriverScanner)
                || CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(TidGameValidChech)
                || CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(TidCommonCheatScanner)
                || CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(TidOverlayScanner)
                || CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(TidAntiDebug)
                || CUtils::IsSuspendedThread(TidAntiKill))
               {
                ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("32947 ( Thread Mismatched )", 6);
               }

               if (IsSystemCodeIntegrityEnabled())
               {
                ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("0392 Test Mode Is Enabled. Please Disable It", 6);
               }

               if (OverlayScannerAntiKill && CommonCheatsScannerAntiKill && DriversScanAntiKill && AntiDebugAntiKill && HeartBeatThreadAntiKill)
               {
                OverlayScannerAntiKill = FALSE;
                CommonCheatsScannerAntiKill = FALSE;
                DriversScanAntiKill = FALSE;
                AntiDebugAntiKill = FALSE;
                HeartBeatThreadAntiKill = FALSE;
               }
               else
               {
                ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("9452 ( Thread Mismatched )", 5);
               }

              }
             }
             else
             {
              BlockInput(FALSE);
              ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("43524 ( Thread Mismatched )", 5);
             }
            }
            else
            {
             ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("202 ( Driver Not Found )", 1);
            }
           }
           else
           {
            ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("945 ( Failed To Start Game )", 1);
           }

          }
          else
          {
           ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("207 ( Driver Not Found )", 1);

          }

         }
         else
         {
          ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("206 ( Driver Not Found )", 1);
         }
        }
        else
        {
         ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("205 ( Driver Not Found )", 1);
        }
       }
       else
       {
        ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("204 ( Driver Not Found )", 1);
       }
      }
      else
      {
       ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("203 ( Driver Not Found )", 1);
      }
     }
     else
     {
      ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("249 ( Driver Not Found )", 1);
     }

    }
    else
    {
     ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("201 ( Driver Not Found )", 1);
    }
   }
   else
   {
    ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("301 ( Driver Not Found )", 1);
   }

  }
  else
  {
   ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("67 ( Driver Not Found )", 1);
  }

 }
 else
 {
  ErrorHandler::ErrorMessage("1001 ( Run As Admin )", 1);
 }

 return 0;
}


int randNum(int min, int max)
{
 return rand() % max + min;
}
```